# What is the scope of the following operation on a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Given the question:

[image]

I am not sure what $Ha=Hb$ actually means.

I can read it as:

$ah=bh$ for all $h\ in H$

Or $ah_1=bh_2$ for all $h_1,h_2 \in H$

Or for all $h_1$ there is a $h_2$ such that $ah_1=bh_2$

And all of these readings are different mathematically. What is the correct reading of that notation?

Comment: It means the the two cosets are equal. $\{ha\mid h \in H\}=\{hb\mid h \in H\}$

Comment: $Hb=Ha$ is a statement regarding the equality of right cosets of a subgroup $H$.  GIven a subgroup $H$, you may have two different elements $a,b$ of a group $G$ that produce equal cosets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ha$ is defined as $$Ha := \{ha \mid h \in H\},$$ so $Ha=Hb$ refers to an equality between two sets.

It turns out that for every $a,b\in G$ and every subset $H$ of $G$, the sets $Ha$ and $Hb$ are either equal or disjoint. That means that $Ha=Hb$ is equivalent to $Ha \subseteq Hb$, which in turn is equivalent to "for every $h_1 \in H$ there is some $h_2 \in H$ such that $h_1 a = h_2 b$".

$aH$ and $bH$ are defined analogously, and are always either equal or disjoint. So your third interpretation is equivalent to them being equal.

Comment: So does the antecedent imply the consequent in that question or not? i ahve been breaking my head and I annot figure it out

Comment: No. Hint: Consider a two element subgroup of the group of permutations on three letters.

Comment: Note: If your group is commutative, i.e. $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in G$, then the implication holds trivially since $Ha=aH$. So, if you were to look for a counterexample, you would have to do so in a non-commutative group. The group of permutations on three letters is the smallest such group.

Comment: Thank you I found a counterexample using permutations